# PHP Countdown to Date

Tags: php

How could set a date and get a countdown in PHP? For example if I set the date as 3 December 2PM it would tell me how many days and hours are remaining.

No need for user inputs for the date as it will be hard coded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use the strtotime function to get the time of the date specified, then use time to get the difference.

```
$date = strtotime("December 3, 2009 2:00 PM");
$remaining = $date - time();
```

$remaining will be the number of seconds remaining.  Then you can divide that number to get the number of days, hours, minutes, etc.

```
$days_remaining = floor($remaining / 86400);
$hours_remaining = floor(($remaining % 86400) / 3600);
echo "There are $days_remaining days and $hours_remaining hours left";
```

Comment: On the day before the event the count down read 0 when I want it to read 1... where do I add the +1?

Comment: Carefull, 1 day = 86400 sec is not always true

Answer (score 22):

Let me play around like this:

```
$rem = strtotime('2012-08-01 14:00:00') - time();
$day = floor($rem / 86400);
$hr  = floor(($rem % 86400) / 3600);
$min = floor(($rem % 3600) / 60);
$sec = ($rem % 60);
if($day) echo "$day Days ";
if($hr) echo "$hr Hours ";
if($min) echo "$min Minutes ";
if($sec) echo "$sec Seconds ";
echo "Remaining...";
```

Try this at your leisure... :-)

NOTE: There is no `if()` test for `echo "Remaining..."`, just coz you wont process this in case when  `$rem <= 0`. Isn't it?

Answer (score 10):

PHP 5.3 allows this:

```
$dt_end = new DateTime('December 3, 2009 2:00 PM');
$remain = $dt_end->diff(new DateTime());
echo $remain->d . ' days and ' . $remain->h . ' hours';
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not as trivial as subtracting strtotime() results, since there are daylight savings and time would be mathematically correct, but not physically. Anyway, for these purposes you should use gmdate() function, which has no daylight savings:

```
$date = gmdate('U', strtotime('2009-12-03 14:00'));

// Get difference between both dates without DST
$diff = $date - gmdate('U');
// Days (in last day it will be zero)
$diff_days = floor($remaining / (24 * 60 * 60));
// Hours (in the last hour will be zero)
$diff_hours = floor($remaining % (24 * 60 * 60) / 3600);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using @Izhar Aazmi solution, you could set this up nicely for display, as such:

```
    public function countdown($time, $h = true, $m = true, $s = true) {
        $rem = $time - time();
        $day = floor($rem / 86400);
        $hr = floor(($rem % 86400) / 3600);
        $min = floor(($rem % 3600) / 60);
        $sec = ($rem % 60);

        if ( $day && !$h ) {
            if ( $hr > 12 ) $day++; // round up if not displaying hours
        }

        $ret = Array();
        if ( $day && $h ) $ret[] = ($day ? $day ." day".($day==1?"":"s") : "");
        if ( $day && !$h ) $ret[] = ($day ? $day . " day" . ($day == 1 ? "" : "s") : "");
        if ( $hr && $h ) $ret[] = ($hr ? $hr ." hour" . ($hr==1?"":"s") : "");
        if ( $min && $m && $h ) $ret[] = ($min ? $min ." minute". ($min==1?"":"s") : "");
        if ( $sec && $s && $m && $h ) $ret[] = ($sec ? $sec ." second".($sec==1?"":"s") : "");

        $last = end($ret);
        array_pop($ret);
        $string = join(", ", $ret)." and {$last}";

        return $string;
    }
```

I hope this helps! It's a nice clean way or displaying the countdown.

Answer (score 0):

Did this countdown until the end of the semester:

```
    $endOfSemester = mktime(15,30,0,5,21,2015);
    $now = time();
    $secondsRemaining = $endOfSemester - $now;

    define('SECONDS_PER_MINUTE', 60);
    define('SECONDS_PER_HOUR', 3600);
    define('SECONDS_PER_DAY', 86400);

    $daysRemaining = floor($secondsRemaining / SECONDS_PER_DAY); //days until end
    $secondsRemaining -= ($daysRemaining * SECONDS_PER_DAY); //update variable

    $hoursRemaining = floor($secondsRemaining / SECONDS_PER_HOUR); //hours until end
    $secondsRemaining -= ($hoursRemaining * SECONDS_PER_HOUR); //update variable

    $minutesRemaining = floor($secondsRemaining / SECONDS_PER_MINUTE); //minutes until end
    $secondsRemaining -= ($minutesRemaining * SECONDS_PER_MINUTE); //update variable

    echo("<h3>There are $daysRemaining days, $hoursRemaining hours, $minutesRemaining minutes, $secondsRemaining seconds until the end of the semester</h3>"); //print message
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a function capable of handling larger and smaller time span (php >5.3) :

```
/**
 * Return a textual representation of the time left until specified date
 */
function timeleft(DateTime $date){
  $now = new DateTime();

  if($now > $date){
    return '0 second';
  }

  $interval = $date->diff($now);

  if($interval->y){
    return $interval->format("%y year").($interval->y > 1 ? 's':'');
  } else if($interval->m){
    return $interval->format("%m month").($interval->m > 1 ? 's':'');
  } else if($interval->d){
    return $interval->format("%d day").($interval->d > 1 ? 's':'');
  } else if($interval->h){
    return $interval->format("%h hour").($interval->h > 1 ? 's':'');
  } else if($interval->i){
    return $interval->format("%i minute").($interval->i > 1 ? 's':'');
  } else if($interval->s) {
    return $interval->format("%s second").($interval->s > 1 ? 's':'');
  } else {
    return 'milliseconds';
  }
}
```