# Run function controller when date expired

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am working on a new project where User public add with a expire date,

In my database I have `date_created` and `expire_date` like this picture:
[image]

I would like to run a function of my controller when add will expired.

I would like to send an email and do other features.

I don't know if this is possible with laravel php framework.

I'm working with laravel 5.2.

I can pass the expire date and date of creation add to my view.

I saw that with JavaScript I can use interval and create a countdown time, but I don't know if I can run a function after countdown finish.

Comment: Look into Artisan commands. You can create one that will check for expired records and do what you need, then schedule it either via cron or the command scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your model is User add your App/Console/Kernel.php under the function scheduler do something like:

```
 $schedule->call(function () {
            foreach (User::all() as $user) {
                if (Carbon::now() > $user->expire_date) {
                     // Do what you have to do
                }
            }
        })->everyMinute();
```

To test it run `php artisan schedule:run`

if it work add on your cron:

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Yes! it work! but i have a shared hosting, i uploaded all files, www.dixard.info/regalo/regalo , and i created a cron job like this: php /home/dixardin/public_html/regalo/regalo/laravel/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1     , the path arrive to the file artisan. But it doesnt work in my shared hosting.

Comment: Contact them there should be a way to make a crontab work even on a shared hosting, maybe the path is different?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need add a cron job on your server and create your own logic as described here https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/scheduling

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly you add to laravel framework
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail. 
Section queuing emails.

```
Mail::queue('emails.welcome', $data, function ($message) {
//change atributes
});
```

and then you can add countdown in php to laravel framework or use some predefined framework function which counts time.

From database you choose correct table and

```
SELECT expire_date FROM table_name
//take value from table and compare with current time
if ($row["expire_date"] == time() )
```

[PHP Countdown to Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735252/php-countdown-to-date)